# Django: TypeError: UserRegisterForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'UserCreationForm'

Tags: python, django

I am pretty new to django and I am trying to add email field to the UsercreationForm. However, I am getting the below error:

*TypeError: UserRegisterForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'UserCreationForm'*

I was wondering if someone can suggest me by seeing my views.py and forms.py that where I am going wrong with my coding?

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import UserRegisterForm


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def task(request):
    return render(request, 'task.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
      form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          users = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
          return redirect('home')
    else:        
      form = UserRegisterForm()
      return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


def UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
     email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
     model = User
     fields = ["username","email", "password1", "password2"]
```

Comment: Forms are classes not functions. You need to use `class UserRegisterForm` not `def ...`

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You wrote `def` making `UserRegisterForm` a *function*, but it should be a class:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
         fields = ['username', 'email']
```

By making it a function, it requires a parameter `UserCreationForm` (so this is not interpreted as the base class). Furthermore it would not work, since the `ModelForm` class contains logic to make a form.

Furthermore `'password1'` and `'password2'` are *not* fields of the model. These are implemented in the `UserCreationForm` as form fields, and implement logic to handle the password as you can see in the [source code of the **`UserCreationForm`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.1.x/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L82).

Comment: Oh yes! that's right. My bad. I corrected it and now my code is working. Thank you so much.